# Проверка данных на уникальность перед добавлением в БД через ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Есть форма обратной связи, которая с помощью ajax отправляет данные в php файл, там эти данные добавляются в БД и параллельно в битрикс
Как можно проверить эти данные на уникальность? скажем по номеру телефона и после вернуть ответ на ajax и предотвратить отправку формы, если данные не уникальны
JS код

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $(".wpcf7-form .wpcf7-submit").click(function () {
            sendAjaxForm(this.form, 'action_ajax_form.php');
        });
 
        function sendAjaxForm(ajax_form, url) {
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                method: "POST", 
                dataType: "json",
                data: $(ajax_form).serialize() + '&direct=' + encodeURIComponent(direct),
                success: function (response) {
                    $('.wpcf7-form').html('Имя: ' + response.your-name + '<br>Телефон: ' + response.your-phone + '<br>Почта: ' + response.email-789 + response['direct']);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Ну можно перед `sendAjaxForm` запустить ещё один аякс на проверку, и если ответ неудовлетворительный - то не запускать sendAjaxForm

Comment: "предотвращать отправку" или делать два запроса просто глупо. Код на сервере должен проверить на уникальность и вернуть ответ о том, что данные неуникальны.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, фигня.

Comment: @Qwertiy как скажешь